# Masonry items overlap when appended to grid

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-masonry, shopify

I'm using Masonry and Infinite Scroll on my Shopify site to load in content, but when new items are appended to the Masonry grid, they overlap with the preexisting content. I'm unsure how I can fix this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"  class="js-masonry infinite-scroll" data-masonry-options='{ "isFitWidth": true }'>
    {% paginate blog.articles by 20 %}
      {% for article in blog.articles %}
          <div class="item">
            <div class="overlay">
                    <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.content }}</a>
                </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.next %}
        <div class="more"><a href="{{ paginate.next.url }}">More</a></div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endpaginate %}       
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var $container = $('#container');
  $container.masonry();
  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.more',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.more a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      var $newElems = $( newElements );
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        $container.masonry();
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on an example in the masonry docs (http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/kwALv) try modifying your callback like so:

```
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
  // assuming "newElements" is an array of DOM elements
  //var $newElems = $( newElements ); // shouldn't need a jquery wrapper
  $container.append(newElements).masonry( 'appended', newElements );
    //$container.masonry(); // shouldn't need this line
}
```

Comment: After further testing, this did not solve the problem.